# Extract data from complex div

Tags: r, parsing, web-scraping, dataset

I need TSLA's income statement in a format I can work with in R. I'm not able to web-scrape data from macro trends' div (https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/income-statement).

I've tried the following:

```
url <- paste0("https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/income-statement")
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
h <- read_html(url)
tab <- h %>% html_nodes("div")
```

But I got stuck when I realised that the info I need is in seemingly unrelated nested divs.

Is anyone able to get this data in `.csv` or in any other readable format?

Comment: The data in stuck inside a `<script>` tag; it can be extracted by I can only do it with python and pandas, if that's available.

Comment: @JackFleeting would I be able to import it to python and then export it to an `.csv`? I don't think that would be a problem^^ I can use python too!

Comment: Yes - see answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If python is a go then here. Regex pattern `p` gets the entire string containing the info the page uses to dynamically update that content (it resides within a script tag and is loaded from there when javascript runs in the browser). That string can be parsed with a json library. `field_name` however is a key which returns html from the dictionary it is part of and so content must be parsed with an html parser. `p2` extracts a list of the table headers. `p3` gets just the date fields of the headers.

I generate just the field names of interest to extract from json with:

```
fields = p3.findall(s)
fields.insert(0, 'field_name')
```

This line:

```
s = re.sub('\r|\n|\t|\s','',p2.findall(r.text)[0])
```

does a little string cleaning before extracting the full field list.

py:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, json
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/income-statement')
p = re.compile(r'var originalData = (.*);')
p2 = re.compile(r'datafields:[\s\S]+(\[[\s\S]+?\]),')
p3 = re.compile(r'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
s = re.sub('\r|\n|\t|\s','',p2.findall(r.text)[0])
fields = p3.findall(s)
fields.insert(0, 'field_name') # only headers of interest.
results = []

for item in data: #loop initial list of dictionaries
    row = {}
    for f in fields: #loop keys of interest to extract from current dictionary
        if f == 'field_name':  #this is an html value field so needs re-parsing
            soup2 = bs(item[f],'lxml')
            row[f] = soup2.select_one('a,span').text
        else:
            row[f] = item[f]
    results.append(row)

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns = fields)
print(df)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

---

Sample of output:

[image]

---

**R version:**

drops NA rows

```
library(rvest)
library(jsonlite)
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)

page <- read_html('https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/income-statement')  
df = data.frame(jsonlite::fromJSON(str_match_all(page%>%html_text(),'var originalData = (.*);')[[1]][,2]))
df$field_name <-lapply(df$field_name, function(x) { read_html(x) %>% html_node('a,p') %>% html_text()})
df <- subset(df, select = -c(popup_icon))
colnames(df) <- lapply(colnames(df), function(x){gsub('X','',x)})
df <- df[!is.na(df$field_name),]
df <- apply(df,2,as.character)
write.csv(df,"data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Success! I've only had to `pip install beautifulsoup4`, `requests` and `lxml`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Just about to add R version as well if you don't mind losing NA columns. Otherwise, I will update to keep those.

Comment: This was very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Try this; I'll try to explain as we go:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import json

hdr = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/TSLA/tesla/income-statement'

response = requests.get(url, headers=hdr)
soup = bs(response.content, 'html.parser')


data = soup.find_all('script') #the relevant data is inside one of many <script> tags
for dat in data:
    if 'Operatin' in dat.text: #this locates the specific script tag containing the data

        #the next 3 lines remove the parts before and after the relevant data in the relevant script, and isolate the target info
        one = dat.text.split('var originalData = ') 
        two = one[1].split('var source =')
        candidate = two[0].strip().replace('];',']')

        data = json.loads(candidate) #having isolated the data - which is is json format, we assign it to a variable
        first_df= pd.read_json(candidate).drop(columns='popup_icon') #the json is loaded into a pandas datafram, and irrelevant stuff is dropped

#the right/first column in the data is now extracted out of the html code in which it resides and converted to a list

annual_data = []
series_df = first_df.field_name.dropna()
for i in series_df:
    annual_data.append(bs(i,'lxml').text)

first_df['Annual Data'] = pd.Series(annual_data) #the list is converted to a pandas Series and added to the dataframe as a new column
final_df=first_df.drop(columns='field_name').set_index('Annual Data')#the original column with the html code is dropped 
final_df.to_csv(r'tesla.csv') #finally, the dataframe is writtedn to a csv file
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. You guided me through this process advising me to use Python. I'm really grateful!